# how can i map an array property in an array of objects

Tags: next.js

i tried mapping a property sub which is an array in and array of objects, but it keeps returning void in my nextjs instead of a string, i used forEach method first then mapped the property array in the object.

const cartegory = [
{
id : 1,
img : '/categoryImage/vehicles_dmtvjd.webp',
name : 'Vehicles',
sub : [{name:'hhh', age:'456'}]
},
{
id : 2,
img : '/categoryImage/real-estate_vkbo6e.webp',
name : 'Properties & Real estate',
sub : [{name:'hgh', age:'456'}]
},
{
id : 3,
img : '/categoryImage/mobile-phone_vy4aaw.webp',
name : 'Mobile Phone & Tablet',
sub : [{name:'hgh', age:'856'}]
}]

const sub = cartegory.forEach(e => {
e.sub.map(f =>{
return `<li>${f.name} ${f.age}</li>`
})
});

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are storing the result of the `forEach` loop which returns `undefined`. You should store the result of the `map` functions instead.

```
const subResult = [];

cartegory.forEach(e => {
  const sub = e.sub.map(f =>{ return <li>${f.name} ${f.age}</li> })
  subResult.push(...sub)
});
```